# This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly

Tags: solidity

When I tried to deploy this ERC20 smart contract in RemixIDE, It give warning: `This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.` and not let me deploy the contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a selectbox labeled "Contract" in Remix tab "Deploy & Run Transactions", allowing to chose which contract you want to deploy. Can you confirm you're trying to deploy the `MyToken` and not some other contract?

Comment: o yes, thank you.